# mySQL Query Optimisatiton

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I store a player ID and how many points they have, at the moment the only index is the player ID. 
Like this:

```
+----------+--------+
| playerID | points |
+----------+--------+
|        1 |     14 |
|        2 |     18 |
|        3 |      0 |
|        4 |     55 |
+----------+--------+
```

At the moment I have ~100k players
What I want is given a player ID, what rank they are in terms of points I've got this query so far, however execution times are high > 0.5 seconds depending on how few points the player has.

```
SELECT playerID, count(playerID)
FROM playerRanks
WHERE points >=
    (SELECT points
     FROM playerRanks
     WHERE playerID = '3')
```

Which will return this

```
+----------+------+
| playerID | rank |
+----------+------+
|        3 |    2 |
+----------+------+
```

I've tried adding an index on the points, but whilst that helps in the explain, it doesn't help execution times. Is there a better way of optimizing this, or is indexing Points the best? Alternatively, should I change the query?

Comment: By the time you have 100,000 players, I suspect you could, and probably should, obtain professional help.

Comment: I wonder about your select purpose 'SELECT playerID, count(playerID)' count function here sounds useless without any group by